# Как реализовать одну функцию для нескольких задач?

Tags: c++, opengl

Например имеем код создания сферы

```
void DrawSphere(float z)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    GLUquadricObj *sphere;
    glScalef(z, z, z);
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(sphere, GLU_LINE);
    //Красный
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 20.0);
    gluSphere(sphere, 18.0, 16, 16);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 40.0, 40.0);      
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Необходимо
1)Рисуем сферу
DrawSphere(z); и при нажатии Кнопки масштабируем

Проблема в том что создаем 2 сферы....и масштабируем все сразу

Как сделать чтобы относилось все к одному объекту
то есть

----->
Сфера1(нарисовать)

Сфера2(нарисовать)

Сферу1(маштабировать)

Сферу2(подвинуть)....

Как реализовать код?

Весь код

```
1.
Изобразить каркасный цилиндр и каркасную сферу так,
чтобы совпадали центр цилиндра  и центр сферы.
2.
Выполнить перемещение цилиндра на dz = 40,
масштабирование сферы с коэффициентом 0.75 .
3.
Изобразить куб и цилиндр.Одна вершина куба совпадает с центром основания цилиндра.
Размеры примитивов задать самостоятельно.
4.
Наложить текстуры на куб и цилиндр.
5.
Произвести пошаговый пересчет координат вершин двух любых(из перечисленных) объектов так,
чтобы один из них превращался в другой(морфинг).
*/

#include <cstdio>  // C++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "gl/glut.h"   //Подключение библиотеки glut.h
#include "gl/glaux.h"

using namespace std;
unsigned int textures[3];
int angle = 15;
float w = 0.0, m = 1.0, z = 1.0;

struct Cub//: public Point
{
    float x_min;
    float y_min;
    float z_min;
    float x_max;
    float y_max;
    float z_max;
};

Cub MyCub;

Cub initPointsCub()
{
    MyCub.x_min = -0.10;
    MyCub.x_max = 0.55;
    MyCub.y_max = MyCub.x_max;
    MyCub.y_min = MyCub.x_min;
    MyCub.z_max = MyCub.x_max;
    MyCub.z_min = MyCub.x_min;
    return MyCub;
}


void Initialize()
{
    //  LoadGLTextures();           // Загрузка текстур
    Cub MyCub = initPointsCub();
    //Выбрать фоновый (очищающий) цвет
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.1);
    //работа с просмотром
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //считываем текущую матрицу
    glLoadIdentity();
    //определяем координатную систему
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}
//каркасная сфера
void DrawSphere(float z)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //Выбираем белый цвет
    glutWireSphere(0.20, 16, 16); //Отображает каркасную сферу GLUT
                                  //отодвигаем на 40....
                                  //    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, z);
    glScalef(z, z, z);
    glPopMatrix();
}
// каркасный цилиндр
void DrawCylinder(float w)
{
    //Создает новый квадрический объект и возвращает указатель на него. 
    //В случае неудачи функция возвращает нулевой указатель.

    glPushMatrix(); //Сохраняем текущие координаты
    GLUquadricObj *cylinder;
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, w);
    cylinder = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_LINE);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gluCylinder(cylinder, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 16, 16);

    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}

void DrawCube()
{
    //  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);// Очистка экрана и буфера глубины

    //Отрисовка квадрата 
    //glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //Выбираем белый цвет

    //Координаты квадрата на переднем плане
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

    glPushMatrix(); //Сохраняем текущие координаты
    glTranslatef(-0.4, -0.5, -0.5);
    /*
    AUX_RGBImageRec *textura = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/glass.bmp"),
        *texturb = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/Sphere.bmp"),
        *texturc = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/glass.bmp");
    glGenTextures(2, textures);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        */
    glutSolidCube(0.3);
    //  glutWireIcosahedron();
    glPopMatrix();// загружаем координаты
}
void DrawCylinderNoKarkas() // цилиндр
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    /* AUX_RGBImageRec *textura = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/glass.bmp"),
        *texturb = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/Sphere.bmp"),
        *texturc = auxDIBImageLoad("textures/glass.bmp");
    glGenTextures(2, textures);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, textura->sizeX, textura->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textura->data);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    */

    glColor3d(1, 1, 1);
    GLUquadricObj *cylinder;
    glPushMatrix(); //Сохраняем текущие координаты
    glTranslatef(-0.43, -0.275, -0.5);
    cylinder = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_FILL);
    gluCylinder(cylinder, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 16, 16);
    //glTranslatef(-2.0, -2.3, -0.3);

    glPopMatrix();
}
void  DrawAllFigures(void) // показ всех фигур
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //Выбираем белый цвет
    glPushMatrix(); //Сохраняем текущие координаты
    DrawSphere(z);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    DrawCylinder(w);
    DrawCube();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.5, 1.0);
    DrawCylinderNoKarkas();
    glPopMatrix();
    //  MyTeapot();



    glFlush();
}
void KeyPress(unsigned char key, int x, int y) { // вращение обьекта по нажатию по нажатию
    switch (key) {
    case 'Z':
        z = z + 0.1;

        cout << "Увеличиваем всё на(Z)- " << z << endl;
        break;
    case 'z':
        z = z - 0.1;

        cout << "Уменьшаем всё на(z)- " << z << endl;
        break;
    case 'q'://не стабильно  масштабирование сферы с коэффициентом 0.75 .
        m = m + 0.4;

        cout << "Передвигаем на " << m << endl;
        break;
    case 'Q':
        m = m - 0.4;
        cout << "Передвигаем на " << m << endl;
        break;
    case 'w'://Стабильно
        w = w - 0.04;
        cout << "Передвигаем Каркасный ЦИЛИНДР на  - " << w << endl;
        break;
    case 'W':
        w = w + 0.04;
        cout << "Передвигаем Каркасный ЦИЛИНДР на  - " << w << endl;
        break;
    case '1':
        cout << "сдвиг влево" << endl;
        glTranslatef(-0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        break;
    case '2':
        cout << "сдвиг вправо" << endl;
        glTranslatef(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        break;
    case '3':
        cout << "сдвиг вверх" << endl;
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
        break;
    case '4':
        cout << "сдвиг вниз" << endl;
        glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.2f, 0.0f);
        break;
    case '5':
        cout << "сдвиг влево" << endl;
        glRotatef(-angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case '6':
        cout << "сдвиг вправо" << endl;
        glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case '7':
        cout << "вращать вверх" << endl;
        glRotatef(angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;
    case '8':
        cout << "вращать вниз" << endl;
        glRotatef(-angle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        break;
    }
    cout << "Нажали = " << key << endl;
    DrawAllFigures();
    cout << "OUT m= " << m << endl;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);



    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);       //Указываем размер окна

    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 120);   //Позиция окна

    glutCreateWindow("Первая лаба");        //Имя окна

    Initialize();                       //Вызов функции Initialize

    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPress);

    glutDisplayFunc(DrawAllFigures);    //Вызов функции отрисовки

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать класс Sphere:

```
class Sphere {
public:
Sphere();
void draw();
void scale();
};
```

Прописать методы draw и scale.

Теперь вызываем:

```
Sphere sphere1, sphere2;
sphere1.draw();
sphere2.draw();
sphere1.scale();
sphere2.slace();
```

Comment: virtual ? это что?

Comment: virtual - виртуальная функция... можно не использовать... у меня просто стиль программирования такой... я всегда ставлю виртуальные функции)) мне потом пригождается в дальнейшем... для понимания, они лишнии, убрал..